# How to use FlowPlayer to show YouTube videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, flowplayer

A post on the FlowPlayer.org forum says:

> It is technically possible to stream
>   YouTube videos directly with
>   Flowplayer

... but doesn't give an example :(

Here is the related post: http://flowplayer.org/forum/7/17501

**How can I use FlowPlayer to show YouTube videos?**

Comment: i think old youtube videos may be , But not the new one.There was some mess in youtube code regarding get_video paarmeter. Which is solved now.

Comment: @Arshdeep how do you mean? Can you show a more elaborate example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it, but here is a third party plugin: http://flowplayer.electroteque.org/youtube